# How to retrieve a list of objects (including ForeignKey Field data) in django (DRF) without significantly increasing DB call times

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have three models in a django DRF project:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = ....
    other fields...

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = ....
    other fields...

class ModelC(models.Model):
    name = ....
    model_a = FKField(ModelA)
    model_b = FKField(ModelB)
```

I was using the default ModelViewSet serializers for each model.

On my react frontend, I'm displaying a table containing 100 objects of ModelC.  The request took 300ms.  The problem is that instead of displaying just the pk id of modelA and ModelB in my table, I want to display their names. I've tried the following ways to get that data when I use the list() method of the viewset (retreive all modelc objects), but it significantly increases call times:

1. Serializing the fields in ModelCSerializer

```
class ModelCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_a = ModelASerializer(read_only=True)
    model_b = ModelBSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = '__all__'
```

2. Creating a new serializer to only return the name of the FK object

```
class ModelCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_a = ModelANameSerializer(read_only=True) (serializer only returns id and name)
    model_b = ModelBNameSerializer(read_only=True) (serializer only returns id and name)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = '__all__'
```

3. StringRelatedField

```
class ModelCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_a = serializer.StringRelatedField()
    model_b = serializer.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = '__all__'
```

Every way returns the data I need (except number 3 takes more work to get the FKobject's id) but now my table request takes 5.5 seconds. Is there a way to do this without significantly increasing call times?  I guess this is due to the DB looking up 3 objects for every object I retrieve.

Also I wouldn't be able to make the primary_key of ModelA & ModelB the name field because they aren't unique.

Thanks

EDIT Answer for my example thanks to bdbd below:

```
class ModelCViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ModelC.objects.select_related('model_a', 'model_b').all()
    # ...
```

Comment: Have a look at `select_related` to optimise your queries: `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related`

Comment: Can share your queryset or how exactly you use the serializer?

Comment: My queryset in ModelCViewSet is just ModelC.objects.all().  I will try select_related and let you knpow, sounds promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for this to optimise your queries and make sure that every object in your `ModelC` does not do extra DB hits